# Different forms depending on user roles

Tags: templates, roles, contact-view

I want to customize the "Edit Contact" form depending on roles.
What's the best way to do it?

- create different templates. It's possible to distinguish inside a .tpl the user role?
- create a Drupal view
- ....

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 4):

You say you want to change 'Edit Contact' - but if you mean, you want a way for a logged in user to be able to be directed 'somewhere' to update their details, then here is one non-coding solution suitable for just a couple of different roles that i hope others can improve on. (The more I wrote this out the more convoluted it seemed

Ingredients:
- one webform using webform_civicrm module per role
- one View with displays set for each role

Recipe:
Set the webforms up so cid1 is the logged in user, and provide the fields you want depending on the role for each webform.
With the view make a block per role or use some php sauce so that the link that it provides varies per role. Stack the block(s) to show on /user perhaps.
Set the link in the block to send the user to the webform that is relevant to their role.

Comment: Thank's pete, I just installed the webform and had a fast look. But I'm afraid, in this direction, my need are too complex. In my form I need, custom fields (eg. new "preferred methods" to put near the default ones), button for address autocomplete,  ajax call, ....
I don't know if webform are enough powerful for that.

Comment: perhaps you should expand your question then to fully explain what it is that you need to achieve. but have you read the webform_civicrm documentation. It has amazing abilities with civicrm custom data etc.

Comment: Mainly what I need is: 1) create a custom template where custom fields are near standard ones 2) put some default values in some custom & standard fields 3) validate (with DB calls) some fields before submit 4) put an address validate/autocomplete routine (Google). I had a look at the documentation and make sone quick tests, but I'm not sure webforms can solve all my needs

Comment: what do you mean by 'near standard ones'?

Comment: eg. some custom "preferred methods" that in the form should be close to the standard ones

Answer (score 2):

Try using webform_civicrm!

1. make different webforms exposing different contact fields
2. you can do that for multiple contacts (i.e. make it into a batch update screen!)

   3. set the webform permissions such that different roles can submit the different forms

Answer (score 0):

After some research and test I think to take the solution to work on the template. Something like this:

```
{php}
global $user;
$roles_array = $user->roles;
if (array_key_exists(4,$roles_array)) {
  $this->assign('customtemplate', True);
}
{/php}
{if $customtemplate} 
   ....
```

But I dony'know if it will lower levels of security,